# How can I find duplicates _id on my Elasticsearch?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, duplicates

After an errored data migration (without any backup obviously...), I have to find all documents that are some duplicates.

Two ways to find these documents:

- find documents that have the same _id field
- find documents that have the same "primary key" field (there is 3 fields that make a document unique "profileId", "linkId" and "type" fields)

Do you know how to make that?

I searched but no of what I found worked...

Thanks.

Comment: In the same index, it is not possible for two documents to have the same `_id`

Comment: _id field is from some other source like mongo etc? Because two docs in ES can not have same id.

Comment: How many documents you have in total? This can maybe be solved by scripted [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script), but it won't scale well.